# Jekyll not updating all files

Tags: git, jekyll

I have the following setup:

```
NAS with GIT Server ---> Raspberry Pi with Jekyll ---> rsync to web-server
```

When the NAS receives a Git commit, it logs into my Pi and activates a script. This script calls Jekyll:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
MYDATE="$(date)"
PROJECT=website.git
REMOTE=username@username.example.com:html
NAS=username@nas.internal.example.com:333

# Log commit
logger "[GIT] Received commit in $PROJECT on $MYDATE"

# Change to git directory
cd ~/$PROJECT
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        logger "[GIT] Directory ~/$PROJECT does not exist on $MYDATE"
        cd ..
        exit
fi


# Pull new version from the server
git pull origin master #ssh://$NAS/~/$PROJECT
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        logger "[GIT] Successfully pulled new code from $PROJECT from NAS"
else
        logger "[GIT] Unable to pull code from $PROJECT from NAS"
        exit
fi

# Build Website
export JEKYLL_ENV=production
bundle exec jekyll build  --incremental
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        logger "[GIT] Successfully built website from repository $PROJECT"
else
        logger "[GIT] Jekyll returned an error on $PROJECT"
        exit
fi

# Upload to hoster
rsync -aP -e ssh /home/username/$PROJECT/_site/ $REMOTE --delete
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        logger "[GIT] Successfully synced website $PROJECT with remote host"
else
        logger "[GIT] Unable to sync folder of site $PROJECT with remote host"
        exit
fi
```

From my outputs to the log and console, everything is in order, as far as return codes are concerned. Jekyll is updating articles, but it is not updating the overview where the articles are linked.

This is the front matter of my latest article:

```
---
layout: post
title: redacted
date: 2019-08-23 10:00:00
categories: gist
post_image: /images/cpp.jpg
excerpt: redacted
---
```

As you can see, it is not a front matter issue. The overview page in `/g/index.html`, which is supposed to be updated when I push a new article, is this:

```
<div style="padding-top: 2vh;"></div>
<div class="row">
  {% for post in site.categories.gist limit:20 %}
    <div class="col s12 m4 l4 dark-primary-color">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ post.post_image }}">
          <span class="card-title"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content default-primary-color primary-text-color">
          <p class="length-limit">{{ post.excerpt }}</p>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-left: 0.5vw;" class="default-primary-color primary-text-color">
          <a href="{{ site.url }}{{ post.url }}">Read</a>
        </div>
        <div style="padding-bottom: 2px;" class="default-primary-color"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

I am at a loss why Jekyll is not updating the overview with the new article. If I look at the output, you can see that it is building the new article, but not updating `/g/index.html`, which it is supposed to.

This is the output I get when pushing new content:

```
remote:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD        
remote:    39dea32..4f0ada5  master     -> origin/master        
remote: Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.        
remote:  _posts/gist/2019-08-23-articlename.md | 2 +-        
remote:  1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)        

remote: Configuration file: /home/username/project.git/_config.yml        
remote:             Source: /home/username/project.git        
remote:        Destination: /home/username/project.git/_site        
remote:  Incremental build: enabled        
remote:       Generating...         
remote:                     done in 7.49 seconds.        
remote:  Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.        
remote: Welcome to the lima-city SSH service.
```

Answer (score 2):

Its difficult to spot the problem here, but if I understand your setup, it can be a **time issue** : a time difference between your development computer and your Raspberry.

In order to check this, you can change your script and tell jekyll to publish all posts, even ones with a future date.

Change : `bundle exec jekyll build  --incremental` **note**: `incremental` works only with `jekyll serve`.

To : `bundle exec jekyll build  --future`

If your post appears : it's a time problem.

In order to avoid this problem, you can set your timezone ([see timezones list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)) in jekyll.

**_config.yml**

```
timezone: Europe/Paris
```

This will force jekyll to render depending on your original timezone and will calculate posts dates accordingly.